# update_user_meta inside a popup/modal

Tags: user-meta, media-modal

I'm trying to create a popup/modal notification if a logged-in user has reached a certain level.

I use the following code (simplified):

```
function theme_achievements() {

    $value = user_total_posts( get_current_user_id() )

    if( $value >= '0' && $value <= '499' ) { 
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'author_level', array( 'lvl-1', '' ) );
    } elseif( $value >= '500' && $value <= '999' ) { 
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'author_level', array( 'lvl-2', '' ) );
    } else {
        ...
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_achievements' );
```

Now I would like to create a popup/modal notification when the user reached a certain level. From here on out, I need some guidance. When a user clicks on the close icon, it should update the usermeta.

## **Updated**

Added `data-id` attribute that's needed for `update_user_meta`

```
    function theme_notification_popup() {       
    $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', true ); ?>

    <div id="my-id" class="uk-modal" data-uk-modal="{center:true}">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close" data-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $level[0] ); ?>-notification-read"></a>
            <h4>Title</h4></div>    
            ...content...   
        </div>
    </div>  

    <?php }
add_action ('wp_footer', 'theme_notification_popup');
```

Since AJAX is the way to handle this, here's my AJAX code

```
jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {

      jQuery('#uk-modal').on('click', '.uk-modal-close', function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();

            var levelRead = $('.uk-modal-close').attr('data-id');

                $.ajax( {
                    url : ajax_url,
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: {  
                        action  : 'km_ajax',
                        'data-id': levelRead, 
                    }
                } )
                .success( function( results ) {
                   // console.log( 'User Meta Updated!' );
                   console.log( levelRead );
                } )
                .fail( function( data ) {
                    console.log( data.responseText );
                    console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
                } );

            return false; 
        });

    } );
```

And here's the required callback

```
function km_ajax_callback() {

    if( ! empty( $_POST['data-id'] ) ) :    
        $new_val =  sanitize_text_field( $_POST['data-id'] );
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'km_user_meta_author_level', array( '', $new_val ) ); 
    endif;

    exit(); 

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_km_ajax', 'km_ajax_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_km_ajax', 'km_ajax_callback' );
```

In console I see the AJAX is succesful when a user clicks on the `close` button.  However, the second array of the user_meta doesn't get updated. This means there must be a mistake in my `km_ajax_callback()` function.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Comment: The AJAX callback is working just fine; it seems the problem is related to the `theme_achievements()`  function. This function overrides the ajax callback due to the `wp_head` function. Anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Why do you need theme achievements at all? All your updating should be done via AJAX correct?

Comment: The first user meta_key ( `theme_achievements()` ) doesn't really require the use of AJAX. I was hoping I could simply use a function.

Comment: Have you set the ajax url to where that km_ajax_callback() function is? Check out the enqueuing section of the link I added below.

Comment: Yes, the AJAX url is working (as intended). If I temporarily disable the `theme_achievements()` function and test the AJAX callback, then the user meta field gets updated just fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it sounds like you need to be using AJAX to update that user meta.

Also you might need to retrieve the "content" with AJAX as well, so as to get the updated information if the popup modal is called again.

There is a lot of documentation on AJAX in wordpress, but here is an article related specifically to your question:
[Update user meta using with ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216140/update-user-meta-using-with-ajax)

Comment: Updated my post and implemented AJAX. Thank you for putting me on the right track!